# Trying to figure out where the c wire is and how to connect it in my rheem rhqa-1010b

Tags: wiring, thermostat-c-wire

[image: wires 1]]
[image: wires 2]]
[image: wires 3]]

I'm trying to figure out which one of these wires is a c wire and how to connect it

Comment: how about a photo of the low voltage side.

Comment: Can you post a photo of the wiring diagram for your air handler please?